# Build a combo box for the sharepoint people/group field

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have a SharePoint list named Technicians which contain a field name "Technician Name" of type people/group, as follow:

[image: johnjohn123_0-1697674210089.png]

Now I want to build a combo box field which shows the Technicians' display names to be able to search/filter the Technicians lists. but when I added a combo box field and I defined the Technicians inside the Items property I can not find the TechnicianName field, as follow:

[image: johnjohn123_1-1697674457861.png]

Second question, Also I have a form for adding new Tasks >> and inside the form I want to show the list of Technician and pass the value of the selected Technician to a field named Assigned Technician field which is of type people/group also, any advice?

Comment: Is this a single selection or multiple selection person column?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP it is a single selection

Comment: Try solutions given below and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Set `items` property of combo box control to:

```
Distinct(Technicians, 'Technician Name'.DisplayName)
```

**OR**

```
AddColumns(Technicians, "TechnicianNamePP", 'Technician Name'.DisplayName)
```

Then set Primary text and SearchField to local `TechnicianNamePP` column:

[image]

**Technicians List Data**:

[image]

**Combo box in Power Apps**:

[image]

---

Then you can access the details of selected technician in your app using formulas like (while using 1st case):

```
LookUp(Technicians, 'Technician Name'.DisplayName=ComboBox1.Selected.Value,'Technician Name'.Email)
```

**OR** in 2nd case:

```
ComboBox1.Selected.'Technician Name'.Email
```

Where `ComboBox1` is the name of your combo box control in Power Apps.